# visual studio code - tasks.json - include path is come with ' ', which is not recognized

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

when I add include path in tasks.json tasks in Visual Studio Code in MacOS as shown below,

```
"args": [
          "-I ${workspaceFolder}",
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "${workspaceFolder}/*.c",
          "-o",
          "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        ]
```

`"Run Build Task"` executed below command in MacOS terminal, which does not include path correctly.

> Executing task in folder src: clang++ '-I /Users/lim/src' -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ /Users/lim/src/*.c -o /Users/lim/src/a.out

Not sure why the apostrophe(') is inserted, and include path is not recognized in clang++. Expected include path should be without an apostrophe(') as shown below, which works in clang++ command.

> Expected executing task in folder src: clang++ -I /Users/lim/src -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ /Users/lim/src/*.c -o /Users/lim/src/a.out

How can I add include path correctly without an apostrophe(')?

Answer (score 0):

Removing space, and change from "-I ${workspaceFolder}" to "-I${workspaceFolder}" removed colon(').

Answer (score 0):

Try to split space between two lines:

```
"args": [
          "-I",
          "${workspaceFolder}",
          ...
```